# Search is not taking multiple tags if the user is not logged in

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search

If a user in not logged into Stack Overflow, search removes the tag after space.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Go to incognito/private mode
2. Hit this URL for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar%20ios?mode=all

This will be resolved as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar

On logging in, the behaviour is as expected.